# Parsing static stylesheets into template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 6 stylesheets which i am generating with LESS. Since i want to automate this procedure i would like to know if there is any way to parse the stylesheets directly into my template? I need a hybrid between the `include` and `static` tag. Static only gives a path, while i want the `include` functionality being able to parse it.

Is it possible to combine them `include` and `static` somehow:

```
{% include {% static 'test/test.js' %} %}
```

Update: Its very important i mention that the `test.js` also contains `{% static %}` tags.

Comment: I may be Captain obvious, but since django is open source You may create custom template tag based on those two tags to provide joined functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it needs to be parsed as a template, it's not a static file and shouldn't be stored in the static directory. That's for assets that need to be served directly from your webserver.

Put it in your templates folder - in a "scripts" subdirectory if you like - and use the standard `include` tag.

Comment: Only problem that arrises is that i'm e.g. using compressed css files and i would like to have the `css.map` files alongside. How can i deal with this?

Comment: You have conflicting requirements, then. You obviously can't both include the content into your template *and* serve it compressed - what would that even look like?